Adiabatic Approximation in the spin 1/2 System
I am studying the following Hamiltonian:
$$H(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{t\alpha}{2}       & H_{12}  \\
    H_{12}^*       & -\frac{t\alpha}{2}   \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I want to assume that $\alpha$ is sufficiently small, such that the adiabatic approximation can hold. I am trying to visualize how the time evolution looks of this state in the Bloch sphere.
When I solve for the instantaneous eigenstates, that is the equations which solve: $H(t)|\psi_n(t) \rangle = E_n(t) | \psi_n(t) \rangle$ Then the equations are:
$$|\psi_{+}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_+}} \begin{bmatrix}
   H_{12}   \\
    \frac{t\alpha}{2} - \sqrt{(\frac{t\alpha}{2})^2 + |H_{12}|^2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$|\psi_{-}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_-}} \begin{bmatrix}
   H_{12}   \\
    \frac{t\alpha}{2} + \sqrt{(\frac{t\alpha}{2})^2 + |H_{12}|^2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
We can evaluate the Rabi frequency at $H(t = 0)$ to get $\omega = |H_{12}|/\hbar$. The geometric picture I have with the Bloch sphere is the state precessing very tightly and quickly around the eigenstate of the $H(t)$ while $|n(t)\rangle$ changes slowly (this is the adiabatic picture).
What I am confused about is this picture of the landau-zener transition, where the probability of the state "flipping" becomes highest at the point $t= 0$, ie: where the energy values are closest together. $(E_{\pm}(t) = \pm \sqrt{|H_{12}|^2 + (\frac{\alpha t}{2})^2}$).
My question becomes, why is it more likely to flip at this point? What would be a geometrical argument for this?

How is $|n\left(t\right)\rangle$ defined?  This clarification would be appreciated, if possible.  Thank you.

Sorry $|n(t)\rangle$ is one of the eigenstates of the spin 1/2 system, which changes with time rotating in $\theta$ when on the bloch sphere $\n(t)\rangle = \cos(\theta/2)|+\rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|-\rangle$

The idea Is simply that when the instantaneous eigenvalues are closer together it is more likely to have a transition from the lowest to the highest state. This is just an heuristic but it makes perfect sense.

It isn't just the point $t=0$ where the transition rate is strongest, it is the whole region of time where $$|t|  \lesssim  {\small \frac2\alpha} H_{12}   \tag{1}$$
and the reason can indeed be seen from the Bloch sphere:

where the part of the Hamiltonian proportional to $\frac{t\alpha}2$ is rotating the state around the sphere's polar axis and the $H_{12}$ part is trying to rotate it around some perpendicular axis. This latter rotation will be ineffective if the first one is much faster, because if $H_{12}$ moves the state to a lower latitude on the right-hand side, then it will be moved back to a higher latitude a short time later, when the state is on the left-hand side, as shown in the picture.
There will only be substantial change in latitude if the rotation around the polar axis is slower than that caused by $H_{12}$, i.e. when $(1)$ holds. And even then we need $H_{12}$ to be strong enough to give a large rotation angle in that limited interval, so we need:
$$\frac{|H_{12}|^2}\alpha \gtrsim 1    \tag{2}$$
The way to solve it mathematically is of course to go to the interaction picture (see below) which means we look at the Bloch sphere from a rotating frame, in this case not uniformly rotating but with rotation speed proportional to $t\alpha$. Trajectories on the Bloch sphere will then look like the examples sketched here:

where we will most of the time have the state spiraling around in a very small region, only making a substantial move in the aforementioned time interval around $t=0$. The precise trajectory depends on the starting point and the values of the parameters. In equations, if the interaction picture state is called $|\phi\rangle$ instead of $|\psi\rangle$, we get:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \phi_+(t) \\ \phi_-(t) \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} e^{\,i\alpha\,t^2\!/4}\ \psi_+(t) \\ e^{-i\alpha\,t^2\!/4}\ \psi_-(t) \end{bmatrix}
$$
and the time dependence now is:
$$
i\,\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix} \phi_+(t) \\ \phi_-(t) \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & e^{\,i\alpha\,t^2\!/2}H_{12} \\
  e^{-i\alpha\,t^2\!/2}H^{^{\displaystyle *}}_{12}& 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \phi_+(t) \\ \phi_-(t) \end{bmatrix}$$
where the mixing of the elements of $|\phi\rangle$ only takes place when $t$ is close enough  to $0$, because the matrix elements are vastly fluctuating for $t$ far away from $0$. So this is in fact a clear case of decoherence.
Actually Mathematica gives an analytical solution in terms of the hypergeometric $\!\ _{1\!}F_1$, but it looks a bit asymmetric. Checking it for errors is left as an exercise for the reader:
$$ \begin{align}
\phi_+(t) &=\ 
    _{1\!}F_1\Big(\!{\small \frac{i |H_{12}|^2}{2 \alpha};\frac{1}{2};\frac{i \alpha t^2}{2}
 \!}\Big)\, \phi_+(0) \  -it H_{12}^{\ }
  \ _{1\!}F_1\Big(\!{\small \frac{\alpha+i |H_{12}|^2}{2 \alpha};\frac{3}{2};\frac{i \alpha t^2}{2} \!}\Big)\,\phi_-(0)
\\[10pt]
\phi_-(t) &=  e^{-i\alpha t^2\!/2}\Big[ 
    \!\! -\! it H^{^{\displaystyle *}}_{12} 
 \ _{1\!}F_1\Big(\!{\small \frac{2\alpha\!+\!i |H_{12}|^2}{2 \alpha};\frac{3}{2};\frac{i \alpha t^2}{2}
 \!} \Big)\, \phi_+(0) 
  +\!\!\ _{1\!}F_1\Big(\!{\small \frac{\alpha\!+\!i |H_{12}|^2}{2 \alpha};\frac{1}{2};\frac{i \alpha t^2}{2}\!} \Big)\,\phi_-(0) \Big]
 \end{align} $$

=== EDIT: ===
I think the Mathematica answer is correct, and it can indeed be written in an equivalent, but more symmetric form by simplifying the second line:
$$ \begin{align}
\phi_+(t) &=\ 
    _{1\!}F_1\Big(\!{\small \frac{i |H_{12}|^2}{2 \alpha};\frac{1}{2};\frac{i \alpha t^2}{2}
 \!}\Big)\, \phi_+(0) \  -it H_{12}^{\ }
  \ _{1\!}F_1\Big(\!{\small \frac{\alpha+i |H_{12}|^2}{2 \alpha};\frac{3}{2};\frac{i \alpha t^2}{2} \!}\Big)\,\phi_-(0)
\\[10pt]
\phi_-(t) &= -\! it H^{^{\displaystyle *}}_{12} 
 \ _{1\!}F_1\Big(\!{\small \frac{\alpha\!-\!i |H_{12}|^2}{2 \alpha};\frac{3}{2};\frac{-i \alpha t^2}{2}
 \!} \Big)\, \phi_+(0) 
  +\!\!\ _{1\!}F_1\Big(\!{\small \frac{-i |H_{12}|^2}{2 \alpha};\frac{1}{2};\frac{-i \alpha t^2}{2}\!} \Big)\,\phi_-(0) 
 \end{align} $$
Plotting it on the Bloch sphere gives the following, for $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ respectively, with parameters $H_{12}=1, \alpha=10,$ and $\phi(0)=\frac1{\sqrt 2} \binom{1}{-i},$ plotted for $t=-3\dots 5$


As can be seen from the image, in the early and late "spiraling era" for $|\phi\rangle$, there is not only spiraling, but also some drift in the longitude on the sphere. I missed that in my sketch above! For the transition of the amplitudes it doesn't really matter, the amplitude ratio $\psi_+/\psi_-$ is purely determined by the latitude, which looks like this:

